# TypeError in Script Tool

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I am currently recieving this error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType' arcgis

for line 22:

invert_out = updateToRow[2]

Could anyone explain why this is happening?

```
import arcpy as ARCPY
from arcpy import env as ENV
import SSUtilities as UTILS
"""
===============================================================================
SLOPE EQUATION"""

def PipeSlope(input_table, ID_Number , invertIN , invertOUT , ShapeL , slope):
    slopeResults = []
    negativeSlopeList = []
#---------------------------------------
    slopeResults.append(ID_Number)
    slopeResults.append(invertIN)
    slopeResults.append(invertOUT)
    slopeResults.append(ShapeL)
    slopeResults.append(slope)    
    negativeSlopeList = []
    print "slopeResults" , slopeResults
    with ARCPY.da.UpdateCursor(input_table, slopeResults) as slopeUpdateCursor:
        for updateToRow in slopeUpdateCursor:
            ID_report  = updateToRow[0]
            invert_in  = float(updateToRow[1])         
"""TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType' arcgis"""
            invert_out = updateToRow[2]
            shape_length = float(updateToRow[3])
            newSlope = (invert_in - invert_out)/shape_length
            updateToRow[3] = newSlope
            slopeUpdateCursor.updateRow(updateToRow)            
            if newSlope < 0:
                negativeSlopeList.append("ID NUMBER:")
                negativeSlopeList.append(ID_report)
                negativeSlopeList.append("SLOPE:")
                negativeSlopeList.append(newSlope)
    return negativeSlopeList 

"""
===============================================================================
===============================================================================
INPUT: Script tool arguments (Global Variables)                                """
Update_Table = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(0)
ID_Number = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(1)                                         #    1st Parameter: Select Update Table
invertIN = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(2)                                          #    1st Parameter: Select Update Table
invertOUT = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(3)                                         #    1st Parameter: Select Update Table
ShapeL = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(4)                                            #    1st Parameter: Select Update Table
slope = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(5)                                             #    1st Parameter: Select Update Table

"""
===============================================================================
Environment(s)
==============================================================================="""
desc = ARCPY.Describe(Update_Table)
workSpace = r"" + desc.path
ENV.workspace = workSpace
"""
===============================================================================
FUNCTIONS:                                                                     """
negativeSlopeList = PipeSlope(Update_Table , ID_Number , invertIN , invertOUT , ShapeL , slope)
"""
===============================================================================
OUTPUT TABLE CREATION: Updated . 
===============================================================================
# Create Output Text Table
# So the input and output can be reported in the tool report window
"""
header = "Update Structure Attributes in Pipe Table:"

row1  =  "| SUCCESSFUL AUTOMATION OF SLOPE CALCULATION!"
row2  =  "|               "
row3  =  "|List of Incomplete Equations:   " 
total =  [row1 , row2 , row3]
for negRow in negativeSlopeList:
    total.append(negRow)

tableOut = UTILS.outputTextTable(total,header=header,pad=1)
ARCPY.AddMessage(tableOut)
```

Comment: Looks like it is trying to assign a NULL value to a float field or converting value NULL to float.

Comment: Sounds like you have nulls in your data. Are you sure that's the correct line for the error? I would have guess it's at `newSlow = (invert_in - invert_out)/shape_length` and that `invert_out` is the offending value. Also, it appears that you have the wrong index for `updateToRow[3] = newSlope` (you previously pulled in updateToRow[3] into shape_length).

Comment: You were right now I am receiving a ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero.

Comment: newSlope = (invert_in - invert_out)/shape_length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it is converting value NULL to float variable.  Add an extra if condition to evaluate the variable before performing the conversion:

e.g.

```
if myValue[1] <> None:
  # ignoring null, continue on
```

or

```
if myValue[1]:
  # ignoring null, continue on
```